# Change ASPIdentity guid to int in VS 2022 ASP.NET 4.5.2 MVC 5 Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I've created a new ASP.NET Web Application using VS 2022 targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 with MVC and Individual Accounts templates. My goal is to get Identity to use my existing user tables which obviously has an int as the primary key.

I'm getting an error in the Startup.Auth.cs class during runtime:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
            getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>()))
    }
});
```

The exception error occurs at "id.GetUserId()" with a Format Exception, "Input string was not in a correct format."

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) Microsoft article is the best match that I can find for my project since most guides are targeting Core.
I've followed the guide, copying the code from 'For MVC with Update 3' with the exception of when the code is:

`await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);`

That throws an errors saying SignInAsync doesn't exist in this context so I have it as it was in the template:

`await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);`

The article specifies version 2.1 so I have installed packages:

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.1.0

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 2.1.0

I'm not seeing what else needs to be updated for the code to work at runtime, any help would be much appreciated.
If there's a non Core github repository you can suggest that has this done already that would work for me and I'll post the solution.